# Dired: use dimmed face for file details (permissions, ownership, etc.)?

Tags: dired, faces

I'd like to customize dired so the non-filename details (permissions, ownership, etc.) are slightly dimmed, putting visual emphasis on the filenames themselves. I like having the details present (I know about *dired-hide-details-mode*), just not so prominent.

There are faces that dired uses to distinguish marked files, executables, directories, etc. but I don't see any I could use to distinguish the filename from its metadata. There is a `dired-filename` text property on the filenames, so maybe I could leverage that somehow, I'm not sure...

Is there a reasonable way to achieve this, or should I just move on to more important things?

Comment: Check out the Dired+ library by Drew Adams, which has different customizable colors for each component of the items your question deals with.  Just place your color on a color you wish to change and type `M-x customize-face`, or open up dired+.el and modify the face directly to your liking and re-byte-compile the file when your done.